# How do you flip whole Docs horizontally 180* with the CSS command rotateY(180deg)?

Tags: css, google-docs-api

I can get basic html text to flip 180*, but I'd like to know how to get a whole Doc in my Drive file to flip using a standalone script (so I can do it repeatedly). I'm aware I can get a doc, open the scripts editor and then use my flippin' project to flip the doc I called, but I don't know what the syntax looks like. My first flippin' success was pasting text into the .html file as simply as possible and using:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page');
    getContent()
```

}

I just test ran it from the dialog box as a web app. But I'm interested in building this one command feature out into several different domains to get experience with the variety of possibilities available in GAS. Anyone care to tutor me? Please?!...

Comment: I noticed CSS tag and instantly comes up with ```document.body.style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)"``` but it's clearly not about CSS, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question. You want to rotate the text to read it upside down? May I ask why? Can you share a screenshot of the final result?